# What is the best way to show information about current Work progress in UI?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have a `CoroutineWorker` which does some background work. I need to display in UI some information from this worker:

- Current step
- Progress (%)
- Error information (exception details)

What is the best approach for passing such information to UI? Here is documented approach [Observe intermediate Worker progress](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/observe). But this allows only pass primitive data and also it does not expose the error after work is finished. How can I persist the most recent worker error for example or any successful result?